# I cannot add data to MySQL through PHP due to a JavaScript error in phpMyAdmin

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have an English-Turkish dictionary website. When a word which does not exist in the table is searched, the php function finds its meaning and add it to the table. But for some certain words, their meaning cannot be added to the table due to an error. At first, phpMyAdmin was warning me saying that max_input_var should be over 1000 every time the word "apple" is searched. I've changed it to 3000 and it no longer warns me for max_input_vars. But somehow it still cannot manage to add some words and their meanings to table owing to JavaScript error.

For example, when the word "apple" is searched, it cannot be added to table and phpMyAdmin encounters an error. There are other words that cannot be added to database as well, "apple" is just one of them.

Ps. 49371 words are added to table through same query and function. phpMyAdmin Version information: 4.4.15.2

[Database Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85iC4.png)

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym6h4.png)

[Data in 'en' table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw2qV.png)

[Javascript Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PihCQ.png)

Javascript error report is here.

```
{
"pma_version": "4.4.15.2",
"browser_name": "CHROME",
"browser_version": "49.0.2623.87",
"user_os": "Win",
"server_software": "Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)",
"user_agent_string": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36",
"locale": "en",
"configuration_storage": "enabled",
"php_version": "5.4.45",
"exception_type": "js",
"exception": {
    "mode": "stack",
    "name": "TypeError",
    "message": "Cannot read property '0' of null",
    "stack": [
        {
            "line": 235,
            "func": "",
            "context": [
                "                lastException = null;",
                "                notifyHandlers.apply(null, [stack, null].concat(args));",
                "            }",
                "        }, (stack.incomplete ? 2000 : 0));",
                "",
                "        throw ex; // re-throw to propagate to the top level (and cause wind//...",
                "    }",
                "",
                "    report.subscribe = subscribe;",
                "    report.unsubscribe = unsubscribe;",
                "    return report;"
            ],
            "column": "",
            "filename": "tracekit/tracekit.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "getFieldValidators",
            "line": 302,
            "column": "40",
            "context": [
                " * @return array of [function, parameters to be passed to function]",
                " */",
                "function getFieldValidators(field_id, onKeyUpOnly)",
                "{",
                "    // look for field bound validator",
                "    var name = field_id.match(/[^-]+$/)[0];",
                "    if (typeof validators._field[name] != 'undefined') {",
                "        return [[validators._field[name], null]];",
                "    }",
                "",
                "    // look for registered validators"
            ],
            "filename": "config.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "validate_field",
            "line": 418,
            "column": "21",
            "context": [
                "{",
                "    var args, result;",
                "    var $field = $(field);",
                "    var field_id = $field.attr('id');",
                "    errors[field_id] = [];",
                "    var functions = getFieldValidators(field_id, isKeyUp);",
                "    for (var i = 0; i < functions.length; i++) {",
                "        if (typeof functions[i][1] !== 'undefined' && functions[i][1] !== n//...",
                "            args = functions[i][1].slice(0);",
                "        } else {",
                "            args = [];"
            ],
            "filename": "config.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "HTMLDocument.<anonymous>",
            "line": 511,
            "column": "13",
            "context": [
                "    var $check_page_refresh = $('#check_page_refresh');",
                "    if ($check_page_refresh.length === 0 || $check_page_refresh.val() == '1') {",
                "        // run all field validators",
                "        var errors = {};",
                "        for (var i = 0; i < $elements.length; i++) {",
                "            validate_field($elements[i], false, errors);",
                "        }",
                "        // run all fieldset validators",
                "        $('fieldset').each(function () {",
                "            validate_fieldset(this, false, errors);",
                "        });"
            ],
            "filename": "config.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "HTMLDocument.new_func",
            "line": 279,
            "column": "33",
            "context": [
                "     */",
                "    wrap_function: function (func) {",
                "        if (!func.wrapped) {",
                "            var new_func = function () {",
                "                try {",
                "                    return func.apply(this, arguments);",
                "                } catch (x) {",
                "                    TraceKit.report(x);",
                "                }",
                "            };",
                "            new_func.wrapped = true;"
            ],
            "filename": "error_report.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "HTMLDocument.m.event.dispatch",
            "line": 3,
            "column": "8436",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                ";",
                "",
                "function sprintf() {",
                "/*"
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "HTMLDocument.$event.dispatch",
            "line": 374,
            "column": "19",
            "context": [
                "$event.dispatch = function( event ){",
                "\tif ( $.data( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type ) - new Date().getTime() > 0 ){",
                "\t\t$.removeData( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type );",
                "\t\treturn;",
                "\t}",
                "\treturn $dispatch.apply( this, arguments );",
                "};",
                "",
                "// event fix hooks for touch events...",
                "var touchHooks = ",
                "$event.fixHooks.touchstart = "
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "HTMLDocument.r.handle",
            "line": 3,
            "column": "5139",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                ";",
                "",
                "function sprintf() {",
                "/*"
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "Object.m.event.trigger",
            "line": 3,
            "column": "7537",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                ";",
                "",
                "function sprintf() {",
                "/*"
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "HTMLDocument.<anonymous>",
            "line": 3,
            "column": "15404",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                ";",
                "",
                "function sprintf() {",
                "/*"
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "Function.m.extend.each",
            "line": 2,
            "column": "2973",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                ";",
                "",
                "function sprintf() {"
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
        }
    ],
    "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36",
    "incomplete": "false",
    "partial": "true",
    "uri": "sql.php?target="
},
"script_name": "sql.php",
"microhistory": {
    "current_index": "0"
}
```

}

Comment: you dont have to use phpmyadmin to interact with your database its one of may tools, or just write a script yourself.

Comment: Right. I don't think that I have any interaction while I'm executing only this sql statement. The problem occurs in the execution of this statement for some sertain words...

`query("INSERT INTO en SET Word='$word', Description='$get_meaning'")`

I'm using phpMyAdmin to see table and error message.